# É possível adicionar Origin no Header de um redirect de acordo com o protocolo HTTP?

Tags: java, ajax, node.js, servlet, http-headers

Estou implementando uma aplicação onde preciso realizar um `redirect` de um servidor para outro e estou encontrando problemas. Ao realizar um `redirect`, recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://servidordeaplicacao.com/endereco. The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   'http://www.servidorhospedagemcliente.com' that is not equal to the supplied
>   origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

O fluxo da minha aplicação está da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o detalhamento dos passos:

1º: Cliente requisita uma página pelo browser ao servidor `http://www.servidorhospedagemcliente.com/Teste.html`

**Request Header**

> GET /Teste.html HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: www.servidorhospedagemcliente.com
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like  Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
>
> Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

**Response Header**

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips
>   mod_bwlimited/1.4
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Type: text/html

2º O `servidorhospedagemcliente` executa um `ajax` requisitando um endereço no `servidornodejs`

**Requisição Ajax feita pela Teste.html**

```
$("#testeAction").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
            success: function() {
                alert('Funcionou Teste Action!');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Agora deu ruim.');
            },
            type: 'GET',
                url: 'https://servidornodejs.com/Teste'
    });
});
```

**Request Header**

> GET /Teste HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: servidornodejs.com
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Origin: http://www.servidorhospedagemcliente.com
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
>
> Referer: http://www.servidorhospedagemcliente.com/Teste.html
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
>
> Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

**Response Header**

> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
>
> Server: Cowboy
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> X-Powered-By: Express
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.servidorhospedagemcliente.com
>
> Vary: Origin, Accept
>
> Location: https://servidoraplicacao.com/endereco
>
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>
> Content-Length: 94
>
> Date: Wed, 06 Jan 2016 18:36:50 GMT
>
> Via: 1.1 vegur

3º O `servidornodejs.com` ao receber a requisição realiza um `redirect` para o `servidordeaplicacao`

**Código Node JS**

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
var http = require('http');

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5008));

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://www.servidorhospedagemcliente.com',
  methods: 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS'
};

app.get('/Teste', cors(corsOptions), function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect(301,'https://servidordeaplicacao.com/endereco');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

**Request Header**

> GET /Teste HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: servidornodejs.com
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Origin: http://www.servidorhospedagemcliente.com
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
>
> Referer: http://www.servidorhospedagemcliente.com/Teste.html
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
>
> Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

**Response Header**

> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
>
> Server: Servidor
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> X-Powered-By: Express
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.servidorhospedagemcliente.com
>
> Vary: Origin, Accept
>
> Location: https://servidordeaplicacao.com/endereco
>
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

4º O `servidordeaplicacao` recebeu a requisição e irá fazer um `redirect` para o `servidornodejs` poder redirecionar ao `servidorhospedagemcliente` para concluir os passos **5** e **6**. Mas ai é que está o problema, a mensagem de erro aparece nesse momento, com o seguinte cabeçalho:

**Código Node JS**

```
app.get('/Cliente', cors(corsOptions), function(req, res, next) {
        res.redirect(301,'http://servidorhospedagemcliente.com/ok.html');
});
```

**Código de Aplicação Java**

```
public void enviar(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String id) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
                {
                    if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS") || request.getMethod().equals("GET") || request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
                        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://www.servidorhospedagemcliente.com");
                        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
                        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
                    }

                    String url = "https://servidornodejs.com/Cliente";

                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
                    response.addHeader("Location", url);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    }
```

**Request Header**

> GET /endereco HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: servidordeaplicacao.com
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Origin: null
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
>
> Referer: http://www.servidorhospedagemcliente.com/Teste.html
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
>
> Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

**Response Header**

> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
>
> Connection: close
>
> Date: Wed, 06 Jan 2016 18:36:51 GMT
>
> Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.servidorhospedagemcliente.com
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
>
> Location: http://www.servidorhospedagemcliente.com/ok.html

Agora vem a minha pergunta, no momento em que um `redirect` é executado, é possível alterar `Origin` do cabeçalho HTTP e para poder enviar? No meu cabeçalho ele é `null`, e de acordo com a mensagem de erro do navegador, ***Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.***. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver este problema?

Comment: Pergunta interessante `+1`. Só uma curiosidade, porquê fazer redirect? não podes fazer o servidor Node fazer um request HTTP  ao servidor Java e ir buscar o que precisas para responder ao cliente via Node?

Comment: @Sergio estou utilizando o redirect porque não consegui fazer uma requisição do Node para o servidor Java. Você teria algum exemplo de como gerar uma requisição a partir do Node JS que seja fácil de entender? Estou começando agora com o Node e ainda não tenho muita fluência nessa tecnologia, e pela documentação, ainda não consegui entender como poder fazer isso.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent é uma biblioteca mto usada para fazer ajax server side.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada nessa bibilioteca. Muito obrigado @Sergio!

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro,Origin `null` é o local do arquivo do sistema,isso sugere que você está carregando o HTML que faz o carregamento via `file:///` URL.Diferentes `browsers` tomam medidas diferentes para tais casos.
Mas basicamente,usando o Ajax com recursos locais não irá funcionar com cross-browser.

Segundo,seu server não inclui CORS headers propriamente,sugiro que você dê uma olhada melhor no esquema de `requests` que já está feito.

Terceiro,na parte do `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` significa que ainda não está redirecionando.Para redirecionar você precisa mandar um código de status 302.

> 302 é o código ou status que informa sobre o redirecionamento de uma página ou documento web.

Então tente o seguinte :

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://www.example.com");
```

Caso dê erro em versões do Internet Explorer <= 9,[veja aqui como arrumar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232017/ie9-jquery-ajax-with-cors-returns-access-is-denied).

Te aconselho a dar uma olhada nestes links aqui :

http://sebastians-pamphlets.com/the-anatomy-of-http-redirects-301-302-307/

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/188

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

http://blog.modulus.io/node.js-tutorial-how-to-use-request-module

Para fazer uma requisição do Node para o Java,você pode tentar usar tcp sockets para fazer a comunicação,olhe este link :

https://nodejs.org/api/net.html

E também é possível você invocar o código Java de sua aplicação Node usando algo como node-java :

https://github.com/joeferner/node-java